# Subversion Edge Console

Tags: svn, subversion-edge

My CollabNet Subversion Edge Console interface doesn't appear to be properly formatted anymore (it used to in the past). Looks like it may have lost path to its CSS files. I have tried multiple browsers, all showing same results. Has anyone else experienced this or know a trick to get things back on track?

It is hosted on top of Apache and uses HTTP if that matters.

Comment: Could you check if the HTTP requests made by the web console all go through fine? You could use Firebug for Firefox and Chrome's F12 Developer Console (Network tab). As to the root cause: this is pure speculation but maybe there was a botched update?

Comment: Thanks @SameerSingh. I was able to fix this (and get a much improved interface) by upgrade my installation to Subversion Edge 3.3.1.

Comment: Glad to help. :) Please post that as the answer and accept it since that was the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this (and get a much improved interface) by upgrade my installation to Subversion Edge 3.3.1.